# How to use json_encode?

Tags: php, json

This code is working but I need to use **json_encode**

```
<?php
    require_once('person_class.php');
    $person = new Person_class();

    $first_name = addslashes ($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = addslashes ($_POST['last_name']);
    $birthday = addslashes ($_POST['birthday']);
    $gender = addslashes ($_POST['gender']);

    $person_id = $person->addPerson($first_name, $last_name, $birthday, $gender);

    echo "
        {   \"status\"      : \"1\",
            \"error\"       : \"0\",
            \"person_id\"   : \"$person_id\",
            \"first_name\"  : \"$first_name\",
            \"last_name\"   : \"$last_name\",
            \"birthday\"    : \"$birthday\",
            \"gender\"      : \"$gender\"
        }";
?>
```

I want to change this part and use  json_encode

echo "
            {   \"status\"      : \"1\",
                \"error\"       : \"0\",
                \"person_id\"   : \"$person_id\",
                \"first_name\"  : \"$first_name\",
                \"last_name\"   : \"$last_name\",
                \"birthday\"    : \"$birthday\",
                \"gender\"      : \"$gender\"
            }";

Comment: your question is unclear.Can you post your expected outcome what you want?

Comment: Why do you first encode $person_id and assign to `$json` variable, then you redeclare the `$json` var?

Answer (score 1):

for `json_encode` function, you need to create an array first then pass the array with in the function.
As example,

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

For more details see, [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

In your code I haven't found any array you have created which you want to use `json_encode`. For example in you code sample `$person_id` variable is not clear that it is a normal variable or it is an array.

Comment: You can also add options to it too: http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php ;)

Answer (score -1):

I you need to build a json string using the post value , then save the post values in an array like

```
    $data=array();
        $data['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
        $data['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];
        $data['birthday'] = $_POST['birthday'];
        $data['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];

echo json_encode($data);
```

will give you a json string

Comment: Are you sure this is what OP asked?

Comment: asty's question is not clear.If asty wants a json string my code can be use.

Comment: If it's not clear you should ask for further details.